# get value of have i visited this website prior to today in js

Tags: javascript, history, privacy

[image]

Here as shown in image I want to  get value of **"have i visited this website prior to today?"**

I have tried "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history" but its returns browser current session history only not the previous.

Comment: for which browsers do you need that data ?

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko For mozilla firefox or chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have to create your own [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) and add javascript code which would increment cookie value by 1 each time when user visited site.

Cookie shall be valid for certain period of time: from the moment user access site until the end of day.

Checkout links below, that are use full for your case:

- [JS Visitor caunter](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/Editor/javascript_visitors_counter.htm)
- [User cookie to count user visits](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cut13.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

As per documentation:

> The Window.history read-only property returns a reference to the History object, which provides an interface for manipulating the browser session history (pages visited in the tab or frame that the current page is loaded in).

And any of the browser don't allow JavaScript to get such history data.

Comment: will browser allow in any other lang? @itzmukeshy7 or i have to create your own cookie as Andriy Ivaneyko told.

Comment: As Other languages not work in browser so go cookies as said by @andriy-ivaneyko;